# How to make an element hide on scroll down in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I need to make a search bar hide when scrolling down the page.

I know this is done in jquery, but I really have no clue where to start. I don't know the code I need and how/where to include it in Wordpress correctly.

This is where it is http://uwinat.o2clite.com/

Can someone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//when user start scrolling
jQuery(document).on("scroll", function () {
    //hide search bar
    jQuery('.header .search').removeClass('animated');
    jQuery('.header-cont').removeClass('search-active');
});
</script>
```

Place this code at the bottom of the HTML page should be ok

Comment: Hi Parfait thanks very much for your answer, I have added this in the html of my page, but I'm afraid it's not doing it. Is there anything specific I need to do with the script given the fact I'm trying to load it into wordpress? Thanks again

Comment: Try replacing 「$」 with 「jQuery」

Comment: Thanks parfait, still no change. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but afaik jquery scripts need to be enqueued in wordpress in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

someid - target

300 -means top offset px

visible - remove or add class and hide target by default

or reverse - add another class which hide elem on scroll

```
var foo = function() {
    var arrow = document.getElementById('someid');
    window.document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        var topOffset = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
        topOffset > 300 ? arrow.classList.add('visible') : arrow.classList.remove('visible');
    });
};
foo();
```